# Where is the ResourceWarning coming from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, google-api-python-client

I have the following code which opens and then immediately closes a file:

```
with open('google_sheets_token.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=pickle.load(f))
```

However, I get the following resource warning, which I have confirmed is on the line of `service = ...`:

> `test_dedupe_from_db (__main__.TestFromDB) ... /Users/david/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py:130: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('172....', 55368), raddr=('172....', 443)>`

What is the meaning of this? It seems to me like this might be occurring from the `googleapiclient` client itself, because I don't have any open file after I call `pickle.load(f)`. How might I troubleshoot this issue, or should I just suppress the warning from that library?

Comment: It's clearly coming from the Google API Client library. I suspect it uses a global variable for its server connection, and just lets it close automatically when the process exits.

Comment: @Barmar I see -- so in this case, do you think it would be best just to suppress the warning? Or does it seem like something I need to look into?

Comment: If the library works as it's supposed to, you shouldn't worry too much about warnings from its internal code.